# Search for a git commit by exactly matching the commit message, if the commit message contains special characters

Tags: git

I can find commits whose message is equal to `$1` if I'm sure `$1` has no special characters with  `git log --grep "^${1}$"`

I can ignore special characters and search for strings containing a pattern with `git log --fixed-strings --grep "$1"`

I would like to have a bash function which returns all commits which
have exactly the commit message `$1`

```
get_commits_by_message() {
  echo git log --format=%H ... $1;
}
```

How can I get the hashes of commits which have messages equal to `$1`, if `$1` contains special characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed)

Comment: Would you by any chance try to spot commits that were cherry-picked or rebased from one branch to another ?

Comment: @LeGEC Yes, I'm trying to make sure that I have cherry picked all commits from branch A to branch B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit] If you want to spot what commits have been cherry-picked from `A` to `B`, try :

```
git log --graph --oneline --boundaries --cherry-mark A...B  # 3 dots
```

`--cherry-mark` will flag commits that bring the same changes on both sides with an `=`.

If you replace `--cherry-mark` with `--cherry-pick`, the matching commits will be completely hidden, and you can compare the messages of the remaining commits to see if they were replayed, but modified (to fix a conflict for example).

---

[original answer]

a. write a function (or a script) which turns an input string, with special characters, into its escaped form

e.g : turns `\ . [ ] * ^ $` into `\\ \. \[ \] \* \^ \$` (I may be forgetting some other special chars)

and use it in your `git log` command :

```
# example for single line patterns :
rescape () { echo "$1" | sed -e 's/\([\^\[$.*]\)/\\\1/g' -e 's/]/\\]/g'; }

git log --grep "^$(rescape 'I can grep * and . and [ and ] !')$"
```

b. (technically not exact, but should work in most cases) if you want a quick way to manually type the message, replace any special char with `.` :

```
# instead of grepping for :
^[1234] expand . to *$

# grep for :
^.1234. expand . to .$
```